# How to export from psql using pcc client version 11 to excel?

Tags: psql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I just want to have the results from a simple select statement exported to excel. It seems like the only options now are grid or text. In previous versions this was obvious from the menu but now I can't find it at all! Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct export to Excel isn't (and never has been) offered by Pervasive.  You can export to CSV / SDF and open that file in Excel. 
In PSQL v11, you can export the data by right clicking the table name in PCC and selecting "Export Data".

If you want to export more than one table at a time or on a scheduled basis, you need a different tool.